# Using PayPal for a membership site

Tags: php, jquery, paypal

I have a membership site in which users register an email and password, and also subscribe to a monthly plan. The frontend is jquery/ajax and the backend is PHP/Slim. So far I have integrated Stripe as a payment method because it offers a simple way to serialize a credit card, fire it off to `Stripe` servers, get a response, and carry on registering the user to my website.

Paypal is different however, as users may have to log in to their Paypal account. Paypal doesn't seem to offer the same ease of use as Stripe, and you must take care of serializing credit cards and other details on your own. I do not want to get into that territory of saving cards etc.

How then can I use Paypal inside of a signup form (where a user creates their credentials for my site) and know if their Paypal payment was successful to continue on creating their user for my site?

Comment: Read the paypal developers documentation. There are numerous ways to integrate it and  readily available libraries and sdk's  also. This question is far too broad for Stackoverflow. See [What to avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I have read and I am still not sure. I started integrating the entire SDK into my own backend and realized that it still doesn't seem like the right choice - to do all this work when Paypal provides a much more secure method on their own frontend.

Comment: Again...there are numerous ways to integrate paypal. You need to decide which one fits your needs best ... nobody can do that for you

Comment: So in which way could I integrate it into a form but know that the paypal payment was successful, without leaving my form? I don't see it anywhere, and I cannot find any resources for it.

Comment: Each method has a flow process explained...usually with diagrams also. This whole line of questioning is off topic here

Comment: ok =/  Stripe took me 1 day, I've been stuck on Paypal's docs for 1 week. It's an absolute mess.

Comment: Yes Stripe is easier. But that doesn't mean this whole line of questioning fits this site. Hire someone if you aren't sure

Answer (score 1):

Use Express Checkout -- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/

It handles every different payment method supported by PayPal, including guest checkout without a PayPal account.